# Child view looks the same on second navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms

A page has ContentView as child, and it has animations from code behind on Tapped event of one of it's children.

When we navigate back away from this page, and then again into it,

The ContentView still has the last animation applied even though it was constructed anew.

We see both the view as it was with the last animation, and on top of it the view as it should be.

Do we have to dispose the ContentView, or do something on Page's OnDisappearing?

ContentView's code behind:

```
private async void OnPlaceTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await ExitFocusMode();
    }

    private async void OnDummyBorderTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await EnterFocusMode();
    }

    private async Task EnterFocusMode()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            DummySearchBox.TranslateTo(0, 0, 500),
            DummySearchBox.ScaleXTo(1.2, 500),
            SearchResultsGrid.FadeTo(1, 500),
            DummySearchBox.FadeTo(0, 200)
        );
        SearchResultsGrid.InputTransparent = false;
        DummySearchBox.InputTransparent = true;
        SearchBox.Focus();
    }

    private async Task ExitFocusMode()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(
            DummySearchBox.FadeTo(1, 200),
            SearchResultsGrid.FadeTo(0, 500),
            DummySearchBox.TranslateTo(30, 24, 500),
            DummySearchBox.ScaleXTo(1, 500)
        );
        SearchResultsGrid.InputTransparent = true;
        DummySearchBox.InputTransparent = false;
        DummySearchBox.Focus();
        SearchBox.Unfocus();
    }
```

ContentView's xaml(partial):

```
<border:SfBorder x:Name="DummySearchBox"
                         BorderWidth="0"
                         CornerRadius="10"
                         HasShadow="True"
                         InputTransparent="False"
                         ShadowColor="{StaticResource SilverSemiTransparent}"
                         HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                         VerticalOptions="Start"
                         TranslationX="30"
                         TranslationY="24"
                         Margin="0,0,60,0">
            <border:SfBorder.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDummyBorderTapped" />
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OpenSearchCommand}" />
            </border:SfBorder.GestureRecognizers>
 </border:SfBorder/>
```

**Edit 1:**

The navigate back command execute, on the BaseViewModel:

```
public virtual void OnNavigateBackPressed()
    {
        NavigationService.PopAsync();
    }
```

The navigate forward command execute from ViewModel A:

```
private async Task ContinueCommandExecute()
    {
        await IOC.Resolve<INavigationService>().NavigateToAsync<ViewModelB>();
    }
```

Navigation service NavigateToViewModel implemenation:

```
Page page = CreatePage(viewModelType, parameter);
            if (root)
            {
                if (Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage mainPage)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        var pageToNotify = mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[i];
                        if (pageToNotify.BindingContext is InfraViewModelBase viewModelBaseToDestory)
                            await viewModelBaseToDestory.OnDestroyAsync();
                    }
                }
                Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Application.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage navigationPage)
                {
                    await navigationPage.PushAsync(page);
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
                }
            }

            if (page.BindingContext is InfraViewModelBase viewModelBase)
                await viewModelBase.InitializeAsync(parameter);
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code of navigate back away from this page, and then again into it?

Comment: Edited to include navigation code.

Comment: Are you actually push to pageB from pageA and then back to pageA? Then you see the animations in PageA?

Comment: Yes. The flow is 1. Navigate from A to B  2. Tap Dummy so animation will run, now controls changed translation x,y etc  3. Navigate back to A  4. Navigate again to B  5. See controls in both positions(before and after animation), one on top of the other.

Comment: It sounds like you are pushing to the old view instead of a new view.